# Matlab, converting numerical output into names (months)

Tags: string, matlab, output

So I am attempting to create a matrix and filter out certain values as I am only interested in values that are within a certain limit. However, the more general case may be more useful, so I will start with that:

Is there a simple way to get my matrix (378x1) to output the numbers as months (or any other string)? So 1, 13, 25, 37...etc. would be called January (or Jan if it helps that all strings are the same length). Then 2, 14, 26, 38...etc. would be February (or Feb), and so on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are helpful, however, but I think I misstated the problem. I want the element number to become the months title. Hence, if I were to use the function find(data < 0), it would filter my matrix, but instead of listing the element names as 1,2,3,4,... (which is what the find function would typically do here) it would give those as January, February, March, April, etc. Is that significantly more difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `month` function that @Dinesh pointed out might be useful, but it's in the Financial toolbox that most people won't have (and it requires string inputs). Instead, you can create a lookup table:

```
Data = 1:378;
MonthIndices = mod(Data-1,12)+1; % Compensate for mod(12,12) == 0
MonthNames = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',...
              'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'};
MonthNames(MonthIndices)

MonthNames(sMonthIndices(Data>0))
```

Since this uses cell arrays the names of the months can be any length. Another alternative is to use  the [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) class:

```
Data = 1:378;
MonthNames = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',...
              'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'};
mapObj = containers.Map(1:12,MonthNames);
MonthIndices = mod(Data-1,12)+1;
values(mapObj,num2cell(MonthIndices))
```

*EDIT*:

Perhaps this is something more like what you want. Here I've set `Data` to some random values, some of which are positive and some negative. The first part of the code is similar to that above:

```
Data = randn(1,378);
DataIndices = 1:length(Data);
MonthIndices = mod(DataIndices-1,12)+1; % Compensate for mod(12,12) == 0
MonthNames = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',...
              'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'};
```

Then we find the indices of the months with positive data values:

```
PositiveDataMonths = MonthIndices(Data>0);
```

Finally, [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) is a very useful (and fast) function for counting how many positive values there are in each month, the vector `n`:

```
binwidth = 1;
edges = 1:binwidth:length(MonthNames);
n = histc(PositiveDataMonths,edges);
```

And we can create a nice plot of the result:

```
figure;
bar(edges,n,'histc');
set(gca,'XTick',edges+binwidth/2,'XTickLabel',MonthNames);
axis([edges(1)-binwidth/2 edges(end)+3*binwidth/2 0 max(n)+1]);
ylabel('Number of Positive Values');
```

which should look something like this:
[image: histogram]

Comment: Thanks! But it appears that is not quite what I meant. I'll attempt to work with it or see if I can find a better way to ask it. In the end, I want to filter my list list using, for example, find(data > 0). That way, it will only take the values from 1:378 which fit that criteria. Then, I want it to give me the total values that would fall into the January category and fit the criteria of being positive (so indices which corresponds to a data value > 0). The ultimate goal is to be able to quickly say: We have 4 January months that are positive, and 10 February months, etc

Comment: @user3229185: Without knowing what `data` is (or at least what a small part of it looks like) I'm not sure I know what you mean. Aren't all of the values in `data` greater than 0? Or are `1:378` just indexes into your data?

Comment: 1:378 are just indexes, the data for the corresponding indices is between -1 and 1, and I need to separate any non-zero positives and non-zero negatives...so this seems very close. I am trying to play around with it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You could convert all the months to fall into [1-12] range by using

```
CorrectMonths = mod(MonthNames,12)
```

Then, you can use the 'month' function. For example:

```
[MonthNum, MonthString] = month('05','mm');
```

returns `MonthString` = `May`.

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/month.html for more details

You can convert integer to string using `int2str` function. 
So you could get the month as

```
[MonthNum, MonthString] = month(int2str(CorrectMonths(1)),'mm');
```

for a particular month.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way using [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) (no need for the Financial toolbox):

```
data = (1:15).'; %'// example data. Column vector
result = datestr([repmat(2000,size(data,1),1) data ones(size(data,1),4)],'mmmm');
```

The result in this example is

```
result =

January  
February 
March    
April    
May      
June     
July     
August   
September
October  
November 
December 
January  
February 
March
```

If you want three-letter month names use the `'mmm'` option (instead of `'mmmm'`) in `datestr`.

Comment: This works for what I asked, but perhaps I didn't ask the correct question. I don't want matrix itself to become months. I actually want it to call the indices 1,2,3,... January, February, March, etc. That way, when I use find(data > 0) it will call up the indices and therefore the months. That, or I would like it to just add all the months and say: We have 1,13,and,130 which are all January months, so we have 3 for January. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3229185 I don't get what you want, sorry.